# Simply display the values of UIInterpolatingMotionEffect?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, key-value-observing, uimotion

Here's a puzzle, imagine a typical UIInterpolatingMotionEffect ,,,

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect =
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
    initWithKeyPath:@" .. some property .."
     type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);
[someView addMotionEffect:horizontalMotionEffect];
```

Normally, you have to put in a property in line 3 there -- say, the center.x

But - what if I (very simply) want to see the value of the UIInterpolatingMotionEffect?

(Or I might use it for some other purpose, say.)

Do I actually have to subclass CALayer and make a new animatable property?!

It seems incredibly complicated to just access the value.  The only trick I could think of was just make an invisible view, set it to the center, and access the value!  Seems silly though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I dunno man. Say there WAS a property (already built in to) UIView, that simply gave the "the value" of an attached UIInterpolatingMotionEffect currently. Then the job would be done, it would be so easy. And by definition you'd be using the "same" physics as apple uses in UIInterpolatingMotionEffect.  (Plus CMMotionManager is still such a hassle - turning it on and off and so on, changing where it's pointing, blah blah.)  Again setting aside my other question, it seems incredible one can't simply "get" the values from UIInterpolatingMotionEffect! (Just to log, for interest!) Cheers!

Comment: I see what you're saying, but wouldn't you then have to set up something (a `CADisplayLink` or `NSTimer`) to constantly poll this "value" and update the behavior properly. I guess you could have an `action` handler on the behavior that inquired regarding the state of that "value", but then again, I don't know how you'd get that value from `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`...

Comment: Hang on - say you added a property, float, ".updatedByMotionEffect", which was animatable, and you had UIInterpolatingMotionEffect update it just as you can have UIInterpolatingMotionEffect update, say ".center.x". In fact ..... doesn't UIInterpolatingMotionEffect indeed take care of the CADisplayLink aspect? (That's what I always assumed.)  so, all you'd have to do is KVO the property ".updatedByMotionEffect" and (again - this is what I assumed was the whole point of updatedByMotionEffect) it then magically updates prpoerties under it's care, in the correct way over time.............

Comment: @JoeBlow have you solved the problem yet? I do need to observe the change of a custom property...

Comment: I believe there's no way to "monitor" UI Interp. Effect!  Concevivably this could help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387406/how-exactly-to-subclass-calayer-and-use-a-custom-property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subclass `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` and hook into the method `-(NSDictionary *)keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset:(UIOffset)viewerOffset` to log either `viewerOffset` to get the normalized values or look into the dictionary that the super implementation returns to get the interpolated values between your min and max.

UILogInterpolatingMotionEffect.h

```
@interface UILogInterpolatingMotionEffect : UIInterpolatingMotionEffect

@end
```

UILogInterpolatingMotionEffect.m

```
@implementation UILogInterpolatingMotionEffect

-(NSDictionary *)keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset:(UIOffset)viewerOffset
{
    NSDictionary *superDictionary = [super keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset:viewerOffset)];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", NSStringFromUIOffset(viewerOffset), superDictionary);
    return superDictionary;
}

@end
```

PS: If you are only interested in the viewerOffset, you can even subclass `UIMotionEffect`. See also the [UIMotionEffect class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIMotionEffect/keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset).

Comment: one of the most impressive answers on this site.

Comment: @JoeBlow It's not like this is undocumented or anything: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIMotionEffect/keyPathsAndRelativeValuesForViewerOffset:

Comment: matt - fair enough.  but he's the only person who pointed it out after months.